# Trying to make a basic slash command response in Slack

Tags: php, slack

I currently have a basic slash command integration where I simply want people to be able to type `/Slashcommandname` and then any text string thereafter, and have the slash command return a simple text string (i.e. `"Hello world!"`) in the channel. This should be public facing, not just ephemeral.

I can't for the life of me figure out how to write a basic PHP script to do this, despite all the reading of tutorials I have done online on these matters. Can someone assist? I've been successful in simply echoing some text but can't get the `in_channel` function working correctly.

Comment: Please do not post the same questions multiple times. I will vote to close this. Please also see me answer on the other question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43773761/how-to-configure-slash-command-response-to-entire-channel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure slash command response to entire channel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43773761/how-to-configure-slash-command-response-to-entire-channel)